# How can I not INCLUDE the system-out tag in the junit.xml report? I use TestNG

Tags: jenkins, junit, continuous-integration, testng.xml

I am trying to do a jenkins integration with zephyr but the junit report. xml contains the  tag, how can I not include this tag in my report? the system-out tag not present in the report How can I not INCLUDE the system-out tag in the junit.xml report? I use TestNG